# Update database values where checkbox is checked

Tags: php, checkbox, sql-update

I have checkboxes in table row and want to add a button to multi UPDATE rows values

html:

```
<?php foreach ($product as $namee): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="box[<?= $namee->rqn; ?>]"></td>
        <td><?= $namee->rqn ;?> </td>
        <td><?= $namee->ccn ;?> </td>
        .
        .
        .

        <td><a class="btn btn-danger" href="?reqnum=<?= $namee->rqn ?>&sts=deleted" >X</a></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach ;?>
```

php:

```
if(isset($_GET['sts'])&&($_GET['reqnum'])&&($_GET['deleted']))
{


} catch (Exception $exc){
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
    exit();
}

$query ="UPDATE `costumers` SET 
`status`=:sts,
`doe`=:doe

        WHERE
            `rqn` = :reqnum";
$pdoResult = $DB1->prepare($query);
$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(                                     
":reqnum"=>$reqnum,
":sts"=>$sts,
":doe" =>(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"))
));}?>
```

I need help to fill sql >>> WHERE `rqn` = ????? (i)

Comment: You could make an array of checkboxes, by just adding `[]` at the end of each checkbox's name. On the server side, that will make `$_REQUEST['check']` to contain an array of all the values (literally the property `value`) of the checkboxes that were checked.

Comment: ok, will do this and  how about sql?

Comment: Well, just loop through that array and build the query. Remember to always validate the values that come from the client.